# Vue 3 defineProps with Types and ComponentObjectPropsOptions (like default or validator)

Tags: typescript, vue.js

From within a setup method, using `defineProps` I can use

```
const props = defineProps<{tabs: Tab[]}> = ()
```

which allows me to have the type `Tab[]` on `props.tabs`

however, if I want to specify `ComponentObjectPropsOptions`, I believe the syntax is

```
const props = defineProps = ({
  type: Array, //can not use Tab[] here
  required: true,
  validator: ...
})
```

but with that syntax I lose my type on `props.tabs` :(

Comment: Did you try with the ```withDefaults``` method?

https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#default-props-values-when-using-type-declaration

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You'll need to use the `PropType` utility to type cast your array.

https://vuejs.org/api/utility-types.html#proptype-t

```js
const props = defineProps({
  tabs: {
    type: Array as PropType<Tab[]>,
    required: true,
    validator: ...
  },
})
```

Or use [type only prop declarations](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#type-only-props-emit-declarations) by passing the type for your props as the generic to defineProps rather than passing a props object as an argument.

```js
const props = defineProps<{
  tabs: Tab[]
}>()
```

Answer (score 5):

Nuxt3, setup, lang=ts

```js
import {ComponentObjectPropsOptions} from "vue";

interface Props {
  foo: string
  bar?: number
}

const props = defineProps<ComponentObjectPropsOptions<Props>>({
  foo: {
    type: String, 
    required: true,
    validator(value: unknown): boolean {
      return true
    }
  },
  bar: Number
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Vue3 (Vite), setup, lang-ts

Thanks @Daniel I had to augment code from your answer to be valid in my environment.

1. import type instead of just import
2. export interface Props

```js
import type { ComponentObjectPropsOptions } from "vue";

export interface Props {
    foo: string
    bar?: number
}

const props = defineProps<ComponentObjectPropsOptions<Props>>({
    foo: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validator(value: unknown): boolean {
            return true
        }
    },
    bar: Number
})
```

Comment: FYI, I am using pure TS syntax to define props, only disadvantage in Vue3 is when you need default values or custom validator, but it is minority in my actual code base, so it is worth trying if you haven’t yet https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props