# Nuxt `defineProps` from TypeScript types

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

I'm using the Nuxt 3 / Vue 3 `defineProps` with TypeScript and want to infer types prop types from TypeScript types.

```js
import { User } from '~/types/types'

const props = defineProps({
  users: {
    type: Array, // User[]?
  },
})
```

In this example how do I make the `users` prop a type of `User[]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue 3 defineProps with Types and ComponentObjectPropsOptions (like default or validator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71055016/vue-3-defineprops-with-types-and-componentobjectpropsoptions-like-default-or-va)

Answer (score 5):

Use Vue's `PropType`

```js
import { PropType } from 'vue'
import { User } from '~/types/types'

const props = defineProps = ({
  users: {
    type: Array as PropType<User[]>
  },
})
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also use a pure-type syntax :

```js
import { User } from '~/types/types'

const props = defineProps<{users:User[], title:string}>()
```

You could add default values using `withDefaults` helper :

```js
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<{users:User[], title:string}>(),{
   users:()=>[],// in arrays and object use factory function to return the value
   title:''
})
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using "pure-type syntax" to define props?

Comment: @Janek because it's a valid syntax for Typescript

Comment: Is there any way to define a default value to it ?

Comment: @selim, yes you can, please check the updated answer

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim it was very useful, thanks for your answer 